# Sitecore how to separating Authoring from Delivery

Tags: sitecore

I am planning a Sitecore deployment, I was reading a "Separating Authoring from Delivery" http://www.awareweb.com/AwareBlog/ArchConsideration.aspx.

Do I need to install and configure Sitecore in both envioronments. In that case users can access Delivery/Sitecore and Authoring/Sitecore.

How can I actually seperate two websites? I am bit confused. Please help!

Comment: Please familiarize yourself better with Sitecore deployment architecture (perhaps through the Scaling Guide -- http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/66/scaling_guide_sc66-usletter.pdf), try configuring a staged deployment, and then come back with any specific questions you might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dhanuka777, as mentioned by techphoria, you'll really have to start reading up on a lot of things before you'll be able to get more direct help.

That being said, this is the basics of what you're trying to achieve:

1. **Delivery:** This is a website running the sitecore web application, but it does not allow users to login to the Sitecore editing interface.  It can only serve up the content to your extranet users.
2. **Authoring:** This is a website running the sitecore web application, but it allows users to login to the Sitecore editing interface.  Extranet users cannot access it.  This usually means it's running on a VM or server behind a firewall.

You will also need to look at how you want deploy your databases to support these two sites.